# Are there rules over using 公認/alternative words to translate the names of professional qualifications using "Certified" in English?

Tags: translation

Foreign professional qualifications that are well known have accepted translations. For example:

- US Certified Public Accountant, CPA, is 米国公認会計士、which is close to the Japanese equivalent.
- Chartered Accountant (the equivalent of a CPA in the UK, Canada and other Commonwealth countries) is  著許会計士. The kanji chosen here refer to the Royal charters under which the various CA qualifications were created.

As for "private" qualifications (ie those not recognised in law)that have "Certified" in their original English names:

- Some use 公認 (eg Certified Financial Analyst (CFA) =公認財務アナリスト),
- Others do not (eg Certified Fraud Examiner (CFE) = 不正検査士)

I am asking because there are some newer "private" qualifications that are known but have not yet been passed by many Japanese and based on my research do not have a commonly accepted Japenese translation:Can one use 公認 to be consistent with the English name?

(One example of these would be the "Certified Financial Risk Manager" set by an organisation called GARP (http://www.garp.org/frm/frm-program.aspx?gclid=CLe78tKBx7wCFVDLtAodiGsAVQ), one could just say ファイナンシャル・リスク・マネジャー, to be consistent with the initials (FRM), but  公認 would be more consistent with the English name.)

Comment: what about ～の資格を持っている? Too verbose?

Comment: @ssb:The question relates to translation of the names of qualifications using "certified" (eg Certified Financial Analyst (CFA) =公認財務アナリスト). Possibly my use of the word "describe" was misleading. I'll revise it. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah sorry I realize that now. At any rate I'll just drop this in here as a potential reference: http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=certified&ref=sa

Comment: (Thanks - Actually this was one my references.)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the situation, you can use 認定資格. Perhaps for a private certification, this is more appropriate.

(A related term to keep in mind is 認証. But it has a different nuance so does not apply in this situation, necessarily.)

E.g.

「AdWords 認定資格」 is a Google-certified accreditation ([Google Partners page](https://support.google.com/partners/answer/3154326?hl=ja))

「オートデスク認定資格」 is a Autodesk-certified accreditation ([Autodesk page](http://www.myautodesk.jp/certification/AutoCADuser/index.html))

Answer (score 0):

It depends on who issued his/her title and how widely recognized its title.

There is difference XX公認YY and 公認YY. Later one has no limitation. So who issued and how widely recognized are serious question.

For example,

This game is WBA title match.
 このゲームは、WBA公認タイトルマッチです。

Regarding GARP,
 you can say
  ファイナンシャル・リスク・マネージャー
　USファイナンシャル・リスク・マネージャー
　米国ファイナンシャル・リスク・マネージャー
　USファイナンシャル・リスク・マネージャー(If US Gov. or equiv high authority issued the title and widely recognized in the US)
　米国公認ファイナンシャル・リスク・マネージャー(same as above)

But you can not say
   公認ファイナンシャル・リスク・マネージャー

Because ファイナンシャル・リスク・マネージャー is not widely recognized in Japan and 
Japanese gov or equiv authority does not recognise GARP.

If US and Japan agree on TPP, each financial risk manager title is compatible between US and Japan then you can say this in Japan.

The most easy way is, to use サーティファイド instead of 公認。